# django - 'ModelName' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I have a model class named `TemplateImages` that holds the reference to images in my media folder.

I want to display the images in a loop on a html file.

Here is my models.py code:

```
class TemplateImages(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='template_images')  # template_images/en/chronological/en-chronological-resume-1.png.
    type = models.CharField(max_length=40)  # e.g. chronological, functional, combination, coverletter
    language_code = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=languages.LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='en')  # en.

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.image)
```

Here is my views.py code:

```
def templates(request):
    ...
    language_pref = request.user.userprofile.language_preference
    chronological_images = core_models.TemplateImages('chronological', 'en')
    ...
    return render(request, 'templates/templates.html', {
        ...
        'chronological_images': chronological_images,
        ...
    })
```

Here is a screen shot of my db:

[image]

On my html page, I have placed the following django for loop to display the 25 images on the page:

```
 {% for c_image in chronological_images %}
     {{c_image.image|file_url|safe}}"
 {% endfor %}
```

I receive the following error message:

```
'TemplateImage' object is not iterable
```

I have searched google, but cannot locate any useful examples.

Can someone explain what I have done wrong?

Comment: `chronological_images` is a single `TemplateImages` object, and you can't iterate over that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've simply constructed a `TemplateImages` object, not run a query. Try this:

```
chronological_images = TemplateImages.objects.filter(
                           type='chronological',
                           language_code='en',
                       )
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You only constructed a *new* `TemplateImages` object that you did not save to the database, and of course that single object is *not* iterable. If you want to perform a query, you should use `TemplateImages.objects.filter()`, like:

```
def templates(request):
    # ...
    language_pref = request.user.userprofile.language_preference
    chronological_images = core_models.TemplateImages.objects.filter(
        type='chronological',
        language_code='en'
    )
    # ...
    return render(request, 'templates/templates.html', {
        # ...
        'chronological_images': chronological_images,
        # ...
    })
```